# calculating expanding mean in pandas with date multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I have a dataframe with a multi-index the first level is a stock ticker the second is a date such as this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [
    np.array(["MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG"]),
    np.array([pd.to_datetime("2022-04-05"), pd.to_datetime("2022-04-06"), pd.to_datetime("2022-04-07"), pd.to_datetime("2022-04-08"),pd.to_datetime("2022-04-05"), pd.to_datetime("2022-04-06"), pd.to_datetime("2022-04-07"), pd.to_datetime("2022-04-08")]),
]


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 1), index=arrays, columns={"P/Sales"})
df
```

| Ticker | Date | P/Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MSFT | 2022-04-05 00:00:00 | -1.1648041378350011 |
| MSFT | 2022-04-06 00:00:00 | -2.352493882690841 |
| MSFT | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 | 0.6047960443400636 |
| MSFT | 2022-04-08 00:00:00 | 1.533852852883288 |
| GOOG | 2022-04-05 00:00:00 | 2.0738583230363195 |
| GOOG | 2022-04-06 00:00:00 | -1.887463559617715 |
| GOOG | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 | 0.49868465858420324 |
| GOOG | 2022-04-08 00:00:00 | 0.900527823711884 |

I want to add another column which would contain the mean of P/Sales for all dates BEFORE the current line for that stock ticker.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Currently I am achieving this with a for loop but am thinking there must be a better way. Perhaps expanding.mean() but I can't seem to get the syntax right to do the mean only on prior dates for that ticker.

```
for ticker in  df.reset_index()['Ticker'].unique():    
    for date in df.loc[ticker].index:
      filtered_df = df.loc[ticker].loc[(df.loc[ticker].index < date)]
      mean = np.mean(np.asarray(filtered_df['P/Sales']))
      df.loc[(ticker,date),"Mean"] = mean

df
```

| Ticker | Date | P/Sales | Mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MSFT | 2022-04-05 00:00:00 | -1.4361186774548342 | NaN |
| MSFT | 2022-04-06 00:00:00 | 0.5922672022039192 | -1.4361186774548342 |
| MSFT | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 | 0.4844687977324626 | -0.42192573762545754 |
| MSFT | 2022-04-08 00:00:00 | -0.4125514467122677 | -0.11979422583948417 |
| GOOG | 2022-04-05 00:00:00 | -0.30860020353979284 | NaN |
| GOOG | 2022-04-06 00:00:00 | 0.1189685515177034 | -0.30860020353979284 |
| GOOG | 2022-04-07 00:00:00 | 1.1730395696068878 | -0.09481582601104471 |
| GOOG | 2022-04-08 00:00:00 | -0.9778323004522275 | 0.3278026391949328 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function with [`Expanding.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Expanding.mean.html) and [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
for ticker in  df.reset_index()['Ticker'].unique():    
    for date in df.loc[ticker].index:
      filtered_df = df.loc[ticker].loc[(df.loc[ticker].index < date)]
      print (filtered_df)
      mean = np.mean(np.asarray(filtered_df['P/Sales']))
      df.loc[(ticker,date),"Mean"] = mean


df['Mean1'] = (df.groupby('Ticker')['P/Sales']
                 .transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift()))

print (df)
                    P/Sales      Mean     Mean1
Ticker Date                                    
MSFT   2022-04-05 -1.164804       NaN       NaN
       2022-04-06 -2.352494 -1.164804 -1.164804
       2022-04-07  0.604796 -1.758649 -1.758649
       2022-04-08  1.533853 -0.970834 -0.970834
GOOG   2022-04-05  2.073858       NaN       NaN
       2022-04-06 -1.887464  2.073858  2.073858
       2022-04-07  0.498685  0.093197  0.093197
       2022-04-08  0.900528  0.228360  0.228360
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. I also just realised that I could just average the last two values instead of doing a mean across the whole dataset each time. I guess I could put this into the transform lambda function somehow.